# How To call a method after a webservice method called in iphone

Tags: iphone, web-services

i am new in iphone programming, my need is when i am calling a method after a web service method, then the 2nd method is called earlier than the completion of webservice method,
please give me suggestion how to handle it.
and not to use thread with time delay.

Answer (score 0):

Your webservice method should have a callback when it completes.

If you are using `NSURLConnection` to call webservice then `didFinishLoading` is called on the class you set as the delegate when the call finishes.

Comment: my webservice is in another class,i want to call it within another class viewdidloadmethod.